# How to read text file and write to Excel

Tags: java, excel

I have a text file with several lines of data like this line:

04498203648;5067670000002534;15:44:50.987;15:44:51.533;546
04498203649;5067670000002344;15:44:50.988;15:44:51.534;546

I wish I could open the file, read each line and every semicolon separated value and insert them into a row in Excel, keeping one value per cell. Also I need to put some format into these cells, like keeping the format "[h]:mm:ss.000" for the timestamp values.

I can read the text file line by line, obtain each semicolon separated value, but I am a bit lost in putting them into the Excel file.  Any easy way or tricks for handling this?

I am thinking of something like assigning each element of a line to 5 different variables and then writing these variables in line to Excel.

Java newbie here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to use something like https://poi.apache.org/ or https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html . However, StackOverflow is not the site to ask how to do things. You should research these solutions on your own, try an implementation, then come to SO with a specific question.

Comment: Oh I see, I will look into these options and maybe come back.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [Text to Columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-names-by-using-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-2cd989db-2b1f-4d89-b17b-534250ff9905)? That will work in Excel.

Comment: Yeah, actually I have a code that produces this semicolon separated file, so whenever I open it it Excel I make changes to get the data presented as I need.  I want it automatically done 100% and not to spend any second on it.  Thanks for your suggestion, Bruce!